# function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I created two functions, one in which the greetings message is displayed, and in the other function a simple calculation is done.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void greetings();
int total();

int main()
{
    void greetings();
    int num1, num2, sum;
    cout<<"Enter a number to calculate : ";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter another number to add : ";
    cin>>num2;
    sum = num1 + num2;
    cout<<"The total number is "<<total(sum)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

/*Every function is down here*/

void greetings(){
    cout<<"Welcome to the function 5"<<endl;
    cout<<"Here we will try to call many function as possible"<<endl;
}

int total(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

I get this error message:

> function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: `Total` takes 2 arguments and you are only supplying one

Comment: Not related to the error, but inside of `main()`, the line `void greetings();` should be just `greetings();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout<<"The total number is "<<total(sum)<<endl;
```

This is your problem. Total takes 2 arguments but in the above line you are only passing one argument.

You need to do this:

```
sum = total(num1, num2);
 cout<<"The total number is "<<sum<<endl;
```

And

```
int total(int, int);
```

Comment: i am still getting a error message error C2660: 'total' : function does not take 2 arguments

Comment: @user8286839 Your function prototype at the top of your source file is wrong. It should be `int total(int, int);` to match the actual function definition.